# Given $X,Y$ both Hilbert, under what conditions will $B(X,Y)$ also be Hilbert?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am recently reading introductory functional analysis books. Here is a problem I cannot work out easily.

> Given $X$ and $Y$ both are Hilbert spaces, Under what conditions is $B(X,Y)$, the bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$ also a Hilbert space?

1. First, I know that $B(X,Y)$ is NOT always Hilbert for any choices of $X,Y$, for a simple example, consider $X = Y = l^2$, then the operators $T,S$ defined by
   $$
   Tx := (0,x_2,x_3,x_4,...); S(x) := (x_1,0,0,0,...),
   $$
   are linear and bounded with norm $1$. However, they does not satisfy the *Parallelogram Equality*, hence the inner product retrieved from the norm is NOT an inner product.
2. Second, if $Y$ is the real or complex scalar field, then clearly $X' := B(X,Y)$ is complete, and consider the inner product defined by
   $$
   \langle f_1,f_2 \rangle := \langle Af_2, Af_1 \rangle,
   $$
   (where $A: X' \to X$ maps $f \in X'$ to the $Af \in X$, such that $f(x) = \langle x, Af \rangle$, this is guaranteed by the *Riesz Representation Theorem*.)

It is also easy to show that the inner product defined above is indeed an inner product. Thus, $X'$ is Hilbert.

What about the general cases? What conditions should be imposed on $X,Y$ such that $B(X,Y)$ is a Hilbert space? (i.e. Under what conditions will $\|\cdot\|$ satisfy the parallelogram equality?)

Comment: Have you tried to generalize your reasoning above? You can look at operators of the form $\varphi(x)=\langle \tilde{x}, x\rangle y $ for some $\tilde{x}\in X, y\in Y$.

Comment: Do you want it to be a Hilbert space under a particular norm, or will any norm do?

Comment: @RobertIsrael w.r.t. the norm $\|T\|:= \sup_{x\in X, x\neq 0} \frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}$.

Comment: You can verify the parallelogram identity which a necessary and sufficient condition for the norm, to be associated with an inner product.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ and $Y$ are both at least $2$-dimensional, the norm does not satisfy the parallelogram law so does not come from an inner product.  Let $u_1$ and $u_2$ be
orthonormal vectors in $X$, $v_1$ and $v_2$ orthonormal in $Y$, let $A_i x = \langle u_i, x \rangle v_i$, and note that $\|a_1 A_1 + a_2 A_2\| = \max(|a_1|, |a_2|)$.